# c program regarding loops

Tags: loops

program wherein there shouldn't be negatives in the equation and it will end when 0 as input

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double number, sum = 0;
    int average;
    int count;
    
    do {
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%lf", &number);
        count++;
        if (number > 0)
            sum += number;
        average = sum / (count);    
    } while (number != 0);

    printf("Average is %.1lf", average);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int count;` has not been initialised.

Comment: Please fix your indentation; that might clarify the problem.

Comment: It's unclear what the end condition is supposed to be. The question title says until 0 is entered, but the loop tests for `-1` and the averaging for some reason ignores `<= 0`. Did you mean `while(number != 0);` ?

Comment: Use a debugger, and step through the code to see what's happening.

Comment: If you don't want negatives to be included in the average, then you should only increase `count` when you update `sum`.

Comment: Always enable your compiler's warnings!!! (I use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` with gcc/clang)

Comment: What do you want your program to do when the input stream contains "xxx"?  If your program is designed to handle interactive input from a human, you should account for typos and other bad input.   Check the value returned by scanf!

Answer (score 2):

In your program you are counting all numbers independent on whether they are positive or negative

```
do {
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%lf", &number);
    count++;
    //...
```

Also it does not make a sense to calculate the average within the do while loop.

```
average = sum / (count - 1);
```

And it is unclear why the variable average has the type float instead of double.

```
float average;
```

And you forgot to initialize the variable `count`.

Pay attention to that the user can enter neither positive number.

And as it follows from the title of your question you are going to enter integer numbers not double.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    double average = 0.0;

    size_t count = 0;
    
    while( 1 )
    {
        printf( "Enter a number: " );
        
        int number;
  
        if ( scanf( "%d", &number ) != 1 || number == 0 ) break;

        if ( number > 0 )
        {
            sum += number;
            ++count;
        }
    }

    if ( count != 0 ) average = sum / count;    

    printf( "Average is %f\n", average );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you didn't initialize your count variable. That said, you should increment the count variable only when a non negative value is encountered. Unrelated but I'd recommend you calculate the average outside the loop, as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    double number, sum = 0;
    float average;
    int count = 0;

    do
    {
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%lf", &number);

        if (number > 0)
        {
            sum += number;
            count++;
        }

    } while (number != 0); //should it stop with 0 or 1? assuming 0
    average = sum / count;
    printf("Average is %.1lf\n", average);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `continue` at the end of the loop seems a bit unnecessary, also in the question he states that he wants to keep reading numbers until a `0` is input but you check for a `-1` instead

Comment: good observation, I've removed the continue.. as for the other issue I believe he's using `-1` as a sentinel, OP would need to clarify exactly which of the two is their sentinel

Answer (score 0):

First of all, always enable your compiler's warnings. I use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` with gcc and clang. This would have caught the first of the problems listed below if nothing else.

There are many problems.

- `count` is not initialized.
- Negative numbers aren't included in the sum as you claim, but they do affect the average because you increment `count` for negative numbers too.
- The assignment asks for you to loop until you get zero, but you loop until you get `-1`.
- The formula for average isn't `sum / (count - 1)`.
- `average` is calculated over and over again for no reason.
- You don't handle the case where no inputs are entered, leading to a division by zero.
- `average` is a `float`, which is odd since you it's built from `double` values.
- You should check the value returned by `scanf` for errors or end of file.
- You don't emit a line feed after your output.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int count = 0.0;    
    double sum = 0.0;
    while (1) {
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        double number;
        if ( scanf("%lf", &number) < 1 )  // Invalid input or EOF.
            break;
        if ( number == 0.0 )
            break;
        if ( number < 0.0 )
            continue;

        count++;
        sum += number;
    }

    if (count) {
       double average = sum / count;
       printf("Average is %.1lf\n", average);
    } else {
       printf("Nothng to average\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the user enters 0, invalid number, or EOF immediately, your program will divide by zero.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge Indeed. Easy to miss a bug when they are so many! Fixed.